# Getting different SQL Server results for same query

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2

I tried to get data from `SELECT` query from SQL Server 2008 R2

My query is something like

```
Select id, name from table1 where date > 2012/8/1 
union 
Select id, name from table2 where date > 2012/8/1
```

I am executing this query on about 300K rows of data.

And I am getting different result every time.

Can anyone tell me the reason behind this?

Comment: `Union` removes any duplicates, if you want to keep duplicates use `Union ALL`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use unambiguous date formats and you need to delimit your dates with strings. Try:

```
WHERE [date] > '20120801'
```

Comment: Yes i used Date in string format but still i am getting different result after every execution for the same query

Comment: Can you update the question with the query you're using now (not "something like") and tell us what 'different results' means? Is this a table or a view? Is the data type datetime or something else?